# How to get my String back after i changed to char[]?

Tags: java

I changed String to char[] i want to delete where char[i] = n, i can do it when i print temp[i]. but I need to get print temp[i] to String again. Here my code

```
 public String missingChar(String str, int n){

    char[] temp = str.toCharArray();
    String hasil = new String(temp);
    for (int i= 0; i<temp.length; i++){
        if(i!=n){

            System.out.print(temp[i]);

        } 

    }
    return "I don't know how to get String from System.out.print(temp[i]);";
}
```

}

Comment: Use a StringBuilder in your loop instead of printing each single char.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Could you post some example of input and expected result with little explanation about why it should be expected?

Comment: example :missingChar("name, 0) then the result is "ame"

Comment: Create instance of `StringBulder` and `append` each character you want to it. Then call `toStrng()` method on it to get its content as String.

Comment: You can not get anything back from `System.out.print`. The printed text is one-way printed to outside of your application.

Answer (score -3):

Build a StringBuffer containing the result and Use String.format to get a string from a formatted output